# Evaluate the infinite series $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-r}}{r^{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My teacher posed an infinite series question to me today and I'm not quite sure how to start to go about it.
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^{-r}}{r^{2}}$$
Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: $r$ from $1$ and not $0$, I would assume.

Comment: Haha yes, from r = 1, thanks xD

Comment: What is the Question? If convergence, what theorems do you know, e.g. the Ratio Test?

Comment: Just to evaluate the infinite sum. And no, I don't :S I'm working on elementary knowledge here, I'm no undergrad :L

Answer (score 6):

**Claim:** $$\color{blue}{\boxed{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{2^k k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12} - \dfrac{\log^2(2)}2}}$$

---

**Proof**

What you want to evaluate is the [PolyLogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), $\text{Li}_2(x)$, at $x=1/2$. The PolyLogarithm function $\text{Li}_s(x)$ is defined as
$$\text{Li}_s(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k^s}$$

We are lucky here to evaluate this sum, since in general, we cannot obtain such a nice answer for $\text{Li}_s(x)$. For instance, there is no nice answer to $$\text{Li}_{2}(1/3) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{3^k k^2}$$

Below is the procedure on how to obtain the solution $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{2^k k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12} - \dfrac{\log^2(2)}2$.
From geometric series, we have
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} x^{r-1} = \dfrac1{1-x}$$
Integrating from 0 to $x$, we get that
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^r}r = -\log(1-x) \implies \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{r-1}}r = -\dfrac{\log(1-x)}x$$
Again integrating from $0$ to $1/2$, we get that
$$S = \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{2^rr^2} = - \int_0^{1/2} \dfrac{\log(1-t)}t dt = -\int_1^{1/2} \dfrac{\log(t)}{1-t}(-dt) =-\int_{1/2}^1 \dfrac{\log(t)}{1-t}dt$$
Now we have
\begin{align}
\int_{1/2}^1 \dfrac{\log(t)}{1-t}dt & = \int_{1/2}^1 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} t^k \log(t) dt = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{1/2}^1 t^k \log(t) dt\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{-1 + 2^{-(1+k)} + (k+1) \log(2)2^{-(1+k)}}{(1+k)^2}\\
& = - \dfrac{\pi^2}6 + S + \log(2) \cdot \overbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^{-(k+1)}}{k+1}}^{-\log(1-1/2) = \log(2)}
\end{align}
Hence, we get that
$$S = -\left(-\dfrac{\pi^2}6 + S + \log^2(2)\right) \implies 2S = \dfrac{\pi^2}6 - \log^2(2) \implies S = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12} - \dfrac{\log^2(2)}2$$
Hence,
$$\color{red}{\boxed{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{2^k k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12} - \dfrac{\log^2(2)}2}}$$

Comment: Wow! :O Haha, thanks very much! I only asked for a hint but you did that in what, 15 minutes? You're a tank xD

Comment: This approach adapts [a general identity for the dilogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence's_function#Identities), $$Li_2(z) + Li_2(1-z) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} -\log z \cdot \log(1-z)$$ to the case $z = 1-z = 1/2$.  Given OP's unfamiliarity with the Ratio Test, the Question may have been posed at a pre-college level.  If so, a numerical evaluation of the series may have been intended.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^r}{r^2}$. Try differentiating, multiplying by $x$, and then differentiating again. This function you should recognize. Now try to solve for $f(x)$ and then set $x=1/2$.

Comment: The problem is that the solution of the resulting DE is I believe non-elementary.

Comment: @Ted Ha ha. Easier said than done.

Comment: I said "try." I don't believe in giving complete solutions here ... certainly not without a lot of effort from the OP. Admittedly, this problem is hard :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac1{2^rr^2}\le\frac1{2^r}=\left(\frac12\right)^r$$

Comment: I assume the OP wants to evaluate it.

Comment: He said nothing, just asked for a hint so I gave him one for convergence...

Comment: Your observation can be useful in estimating the error of a partial sum; truncating the series after $r=N$ removes a tail whose combined terms are less than $2^{-N}$.