# Evaluate the series $\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{2^k k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove that

$$\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{2^k k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{1}{2}\log(2)^2$$

without using the well-known $\operatorname{Li}_2\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$ ?

Edited : Thanks for L.F , but I should have made it clear that I want an answer using only series manipulations .

Comment: I don't think this is going to be an easy one; the problem easily generalises to $\sum \frac{x^k}{k^2}$ (so setting $x=\frac{1}{2}$ gives your problem back), so if there existed a nice way to do this problem, I would imagine the generalisation wouldn't be so far behind, and the Basel problem would be less infamous!

Comment: @FireGarden, I believe there is a way to solve the problem , and generalization would be impossible since we only know the values listed for the dilogarithm . I think it wouldn't be impossible to prove that the sum is $\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{1}{2} \log^2(2)$ , knowing that the first term is the alternating zeta function .

Comment: I was hoping for an answer without using integration . I meant by pure series manipulation .

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. The answer below as well as the answer to the "duplicate" question are just disguised derivations of the identity $$\mathrm{Li}_2 (z) +\mathrm{Li}_2 (1-z) = \zeta(2)- \ln z \ln (1-z) $$ without calling dilogarithms "dilogarithms". This is clearly not the answer OP was looking for. Vote to reopen.

Comment: @O.L , my initial intention was solving the series without integration !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply [Euler Series Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler.27s_transform) to the series
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{12}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2}\tag{1}
$$
which yields
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi^2}{12}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n-1}\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k+1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n-1}\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{j}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n-1}\frac1{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{j+1}{k+1}\frac{(-1)^k}{j+1}\tag{5}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n-1}\frac1{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^n\frac1{j+1}\tag{6}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}\frac1{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1j\tag{7}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n2^n}\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Use the series for $\log(2)=-\log\left(1-\frac12\right)$
$$
\log(2)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{k2^k}\tag{9}
$$
and square to get
$$
\begin{align}
\log(2)^2
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{mn2^{m+n}}\tag{10}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{m(m+n)2^{m+n}}+\frac1{n(m+n)2^{m+n}}\tag{11}\\
&=2\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{m(m+n)2^{m+n}}\tag{12}\\
&=2\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac1{mn2^n}\tag{13}\\
&=2\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=m}^\infty\frac1{mn2^n}-2\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{m^22^m}\tag{14}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^n\frac1{mn2^n}-2\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{m^22^m}\tag{15}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n2^n}-2\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{m^22^m}\tag{16}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-2\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{m^22^m}\tag{17}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{m^22^m}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac12\log(2)^2\tag{18}
$$

---

**Explanation**

$\hphantom{0}(2)$ Euler Series Transformation
$\hphantom{0}(3)$ $\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}$
$\hphantom{0}(4)$ $\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{j}{k}$
$\hphantom{0}(5)$ $\binom{j+1}{k+1}=\frac{j+1}{k+1}\binom{j}{k}$
$\hphantom{0}(6)$ $\sum_{k=0}^j(-1)^k\binom{j+1}{k+1}=1$
$\hphantom{0}(7)$ $j\mapsto j-1$ and $n\mapsto n-1$
$\hphantom{0}(8)$ collect $H_n$
$(10)$ multiply the series
$(11)$ $\frac1{mn}=\frac1{m(m+n)}+\frac1{n(m+n)}$
$(12)$ use symmetry
$(13)$ $n\mapsto n-m$
$(14)$ add and subtract the terms for $m=n$
$(15)$ change order of summation
$(16)$ collect $H_n$
$(17)$ use $(8)$

Answer (score 6):

$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}x^{k-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}\Rightarrow \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^kk^2}=-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln (1-x)}{x}\,dx$$

Notice that:

$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln (1-x)}{x}\,dx\overset{x\to \frac{x}{2}}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1-\frac{x}{2})}{x}\,dx \overset{ \text{IBP}}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{2-x}\,dt \overset{x\to 1-x}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1-x)}{1+x}\,dx\end{aligned}$$

Now consider:

$$f(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1-tx)}{1+x}\,dx$$ We want $-f(1)$. Differentiate: $$\begin{aligned} f'(t) &= \int_0^1 \frac{x\,dx}{(tx-1)(1+x)} \\&= \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{tx-1}+\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(t+1)(1+x)}-\int_0^1 \frac{t\,dx}{(tx-1)(t+1)}\\& =\frac{\ln (1-t)}{t}+\frac{\ln 2}{t+1} -\frac{\ln (1-t)}{1+t}\end{aligned}$$

Hence:

$$f(1) =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1-t)}{t}\,dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln 2}{t+1}\,dt-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1-t)}{1+t}\,dt}_{f(1)}$$

$$\Rightarrow -f(1) =\frac{1}{2}\left(-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1-t)}{t}\,dt-\int_0^1\frac{\ln 2}{t+1}\right)\,dt=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}$$

Comment: ..I don't understand the implication in the first line!?

Comment: @FireGarden Integrate, divide by $x$, integrate again.

Comment: @FireGarden See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388006/evaluate-the-infinite-series-sum-r-1-infty-frac2-rr2?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

We can use the following identity

> $$ \mathrm{Li}_2(1-x) = -\mathrm{Li}_2 \left( {1-\frac {1}{x}} \right)- \frac{1}{2}\, \ln^2 \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)-\zeta(2) ,$$

which relates two dilogarithm functions. Now, in your case, letting $x=\frac{1}{2}$, we have

$$ \mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = -\mathrm{Li}_2 \left( {-1} \right)- \frac{1}{2}\, \ln^2 \left( 2 \right)-\zeta(2)$$

$$ = \frac{\zeta(2)}{2}- \frac{1}{2}\, \ln^2 \left( {2} \right)-\zeta(2)$$

> $$\implies  \mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)= \frac{1}{2}\ln^2\left( {2} \right)-\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}.  $$

**Note:**

> $$ \mathrm{Li}_2(-1)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}= -\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}. $$

Comment: Thanks Mhenni for the answer . But as I said I am interested in a solution using only series manipulations .

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: By the way, are you the downvoter?

Comment: yes ! , I noted in my question that the answer shouldn't use the identity for $\operatorname{Li}_2 \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: But, I used $\mathrm{Li}_{2}(-1)$!!

Comment: My main concern was using only series to prove the identity .

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: This is series approach!! Do you know what is the series of $\mathrm{Li}_{2}(-1)$?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: This is a very useful relation!